# discord py. Can't send reason in embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a server blacklist bot. And when the command is executed it sends an embed to #blackllisted-servers.

```
@client.command(name="serverblacklist")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def server_blacklist(ctx, guild_id: int,*,reason="No reason specified"):
    await ctx.send("Server has been blaclisted! " + reason)
    channel = client.get_channel(828860015783575632)

    embed = Embed(title="Server blacklisted", description="**Added by:** <@671577320632614962> \n**Reason:** {reason}", colour=0xFF0000)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    # To add a guild id to the file:
    with open("blacklisted guilds.txt", "a") as blacklistfile:
        blacklistfile.write(f"{guild_id}\n")
```

My questions are:

1. How do I specify a reason so it doesn't send {reason} like this https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/614194370316337174/829412952385257513/unknown.png
2. I keep all the blacklisted server ids in .txt files. Is it possible to fetch the added id when executing command. and add a **Server:** (serverid)
3. How do I mention user, cause {message.author.mention} doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please don't ask multiple questions in one contribution as they all deal with a different topic.

**For your first question:** You have to use `f-strings` in order to show it correctly.

**Your new description would be**:

```py
description=f"**Added by:** {ctx.message.author.name} \n**Reason:** {reason}"
```

Otherwise it will just display: "**Added by:** <@671577320632614962> + **Reason:** {reason}"

To mention a user/the author of the message, use the following:

```py
f"{ctx.message.author.name}"
```

You can also indeed read out a text file but I would rather work with a JSON-file, depends on you.